# clear mysql query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to implement this mysql statement in codeigniter

```
$this->db->where('id', 30);
$this->db->update('sample_table', array('user_name'=>'John'));

// this line 

$this->db->where('sample_table_id', 30);
$this->db->update('sample_table_revision', array('user_name'=>'John'));
```

How to clear the query at this line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
$this->db->reset_query()
```

Read more from  [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#resetting-query-builder)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can pass the where condition array in third parameter like

```
$this->db->update('sample_table_revision', 
                     array('user_name'=>'John'), 
                          array('sample_table_id'=>30));
```